# Ruby on rails, ajax on pagination bug, works before changing site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I got this unusual problem in my rails app. I have a view where i'm using RESTful routes.
In my view do i have an index and a show action. In my index do i use will_paginate for some rows i'm printing from a table. When i press next on the pagination it makes a ajax request and render the next 5 rows. Everything works fine first time i load the site and when i click next it is processed to the controller by JS. But when i click show on one of the posts i print from my table and is directed to the show.html.erb and press on a button to come back to the index i get the unusual problem with the ajax call on my pagination. If i click next for example it is processed by HTML. If i update the index again, the ajax call work again.

index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= post.name %>
<%= link_to 'show', post_path(post) %>
<% end %>
<div class="show_pagination"><%= render 'posts/pagination' %></div>
```

_pagination.html.erb

```
<div class="pagination">
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false %>
</div>
```

index.js.html

```
$('.show_pagination').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("posts/pagination")) %>');
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @posts.name %>
<%= link_to 'All posts', posts_path %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def index
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5).all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def show
@posts = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", '.show_pagination .pagination a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I do not get any errors in my javascript console, or in the rails console.
I'm using ROR 4, and is using the Jquery and Jquery ui gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did install Jquery-turbolinks gem and everything is working fine now.

So if anyone else than me have the same problem is there a link to jquery turbolinks here.
https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

Comment: Thanks i will do that. But my challenge is that when i go to the show.html.erb and back again the ajax call is not working. But if i update the index again, it do all work again.

Comment: are you using turbolinks?

Comment: yes I am. It's default in rails 4. Any suggestions?

Comment: You replied that with jquery-turbolinks everything is fine. Isn't it?

Comment: It is. Was just thinking you might did know another way.

Comment: no. your self-answer is correct. If you aree usinng turbolinks you need to execute what you are executing on document.ready also on page:load and that is what the you included does. So that is the way to go.